# Unable to set focus on an input of Twitter Bootstrap's Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, focus, bootstrap-typeahead

When I remove these attributes:

```
data-source="<?=str_replace('"', '&quot;', json_encode($equipment, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS)); ?>" data-items="4" data-provide="typeahead"
```

I am able to perform this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.first').focus();
});
```

This is my HTML markup for this:

```
<div class="itemx">
    <input type="text" class="input-large first" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Equipment Name/Label" name="equip[]" data-source="<?=str_replace('"', '&quot;', json_encode($equipment, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS)); ?>" data-items="4" data-provide="typeahead" />
    <input type="text" class="input-large second" placeholder="Quantity" name="quant[]" />
</div>
```

**NOTE:** Typeahead works well an this it's nothing wrong with this:

```
data-source="<?=str_replace('"', '&quot;', json_encode($equipment, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS)); ?>"
```

Answer (score 8):

I recently had this issue.  It fixed itself when I declared the `.typeahead()` code block first, and then gave the field focus.  If I reversed the order, the `.typeahead()` functionality broke.

```
$('#myField').typeahead({
    ...
});

$('#myField').focus();
```

Comment: +1 This works. Using html5 `<input ... autofocus>` seems to work as well.

Comment: Never. I repeat NEVER use autofocus attribute on input element with typeahead. It will work everywhere but not on iPhone. And you will literally pull your hair out!

Answer (score 8):

typeahead has it's own version of focus method. Default behaviour is prevented of focus event so the only way is to keep typeahead reference.

```
var typeaheadReference = $('.typeahead').typeahead({ ... };
```

then you just call `typeaheadReference.focus();`

Answer (score 4):

Don't ask me why, but this is the only thing that worked for me:

```
setTimeout("$('[name=search_input]').focus();", 0)
```

Comment: Old answer, but until today (02/2020), i didn't find good arguments to why this working like that :b

Answer (score 2):

Typeahead is actively blocking default focus event.  I am not sure why (perhaps there is a use case where focus breaks typeahead, I haven't seen it).

In the [typeahead.js source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js) (at the end lines 316 to 321):

```
  $(document).on('focus.typeahead.data-api', '[data-provide="typeahead"]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)
    if ($this.data('typeahead')) return
    e.preventDefault()
    $this.typeahead($this.data())
  })
```

Change to:

```
  $(document).on('focus.typeahead.data-api', '[data-provide="typeahead"]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)
    if ($this.data('typeahead')) return true
    $this.typeahead($this.data())
  })
```

Returning true allows the focus event to complete (only runs this after first focus when typeahead is established) and removing the `e.preventDefault()` call allows focus to fire on initial setup.

I have a [pull request](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6753) in for the change - will update answer with authors' response.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version you are using, I bumped into this issue in 0.9.3.

Not the cleanest, but you can try to set a timeout:

setTimeout(function(){ $('.first').focus(); }, 0);

Answer (score 1):

Using typeahead.js 0.10.2 the solution specified by Evil Closet Monkey *almost* worked for me. As specified, you have to set focus after the call to "typeahead", but keep in mind that the "typeahead" invocation will manipulate the DOM and add additional elements. After calling "typeahead", locate the element representing your input box and set focus to that. As shown below, the input element has the class "tt-input" assigned to it.

Example:

html:

```
<div id="levelSearchBox" style="clear: both">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search" data-bind="value: selectedRootLevel" />
</div>
```

js:

```
    $('#levelSearchBox .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 0,
        autoselect: true
    }, {
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: levels.ttAdapter()
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function ($e, datum) {
        selectedCallBack(datum["name"]);
    });

    $('#levelSearchBox .tt-input').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the input is hidden.

```
$('input:visible').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle for people to quickly test the version of the library
http://jsfiddle.net/uryUP/

I realized another piece of my code was disabling my input box causing the focus to fail, but this helped me realize it was my code and not the library

```
$('#locationSearchText').typeahead({
            minLength: 1,
            highlight: true
        },
        {
            source: function (query, process) {
                return process([{value:'abcdefg'}]);
            }
        });

$('#locationSearchText').focus().typeahead('val', 'abc');
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up using the click event instead of focus and it works for me.