# Bootstrap-3-typeahead: How to change focus to another input after selected item into dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using [Bootstrap 3 Typeahead 4.0.2](https://openbase.io/js/bootstrap-3-typeahead) and i would like to know how can i change Typeahead input focus to another input text after i select one item inside list? I found some similar questions but i didn't find the correct way to solve this:

1. [Angularjs ui typeahead to focus after select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955353/angularjs-ui-typeahead-to-focus-after-select)
2. [Focus on other input after typeahead-on-select angular-ui-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955332/focus-on-other-input-after-typeahead-on-select-angular-ui-bootstrap)
3. [How to get Bootstrap typeahead click result before the input change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777398/how-to-get-bootstrap-typeahead-click-result-before-the-input-change-event)

When i select some item inside input text, the focus keep on this input text but i would like to change this focus to next input text after i select an item. Below are the html code and bootstap typeahead that i'm using:

**HTML**

```html
<input type="text" name="products" id="products" data-provide="typeahead" class="form-control typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type something" />

<input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Type price" />
```

**Bootstrap 3 Typeahead**

```
            $('#products').typeahead({ 

                source: function ( query, result )  

                {
                    result ( $.map(data, function (item)
                        {
                            return item.product;
                        }
                    ));

                },

                  afterSelect: function(data) {

   $('#price').focus();

  },    

    });
```

As the Typeahead code above, i tryed to insert jquery focus event *$('#price').focus();* inside Typeahead afterSelect event but not working. In this case, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625866/unable-to-set-focus-on-an-input-of-twitter-bootstraps-typeahead). I just insert the code below inside **Typeahead afterSelect** event:

```
setTimeout("$('#price').focus();", 0)
```

The code above works well but i don't know why **setTimeout** has a function to changed focus when i select an item inside list. Anyway, it worked for me :p